# Magento 2.1.7 static content deploy creates _temp.min.js file instead of .js file

Tags: magento-2.1, setup-upgrade, static-content-deploy, minified-js

In Magento 2.1.7 when I have customized some js as per our requirement 
in `app\design\frontend\vendor\theme\Magento_ProductVideo` and then fire following commands

> ```
> php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:upgrade
> php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
> ```

Then I found the files are renamed xxx_temp.min.js instead of xxx.js in pub/static area.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to disable js minification in admin configuration.

Comment: @Rizwan I have tried it, after that, I have fired the above commands again also. But no luck.

Comment: The minification wasn't the problem, actually the core file in vendor directory was renamed `xxx_temp.js`. So after minification, it becomes `xxx_temp.min.js`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable the minify javascript files to **NO**

[image]

After that remove `pub/static/frontend` and `pub/static/_cache` directories.

Flush your Magento cache using CLI. `php bin/magento c:f`
Deploy static content `php bin/magento s:s:d`

Thanks